# xcode project framework folder different version from Pods framework folder

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I am inheriting an existing code base, not scratch project.

In my xcode app project I have a framework folder with many frameworks inside it.
In my xcode Pods project I have Pods folder with name of the frameworks as folders and framework.h

However I noticed the version of these frame work differs, and it appears xcode is using the one from the app project, ignoring the one from the pods project.

How can I correct this? what is the proper approach?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like whoever migrated to Cocoapods didn't quite understand how they work. Anything that's being pulled in as a pod should not exist in the local project. I'd just nuke all those local frameworks (assuming that they're duplicating what's in the Podfile), clean the project and try running from there.

Comment: so there should not be any framework folder inside the app project? I see many tutorial online that has that folder

Comment: So there should be two Frameworks folders visible in Xcode, one will be in your project and the other will be in the Pods subproject. The project Frameworks folder should have some Apple frameworks and a framework called "Pods_(your project name)", as well as whatever frameworks aren't listed in the Podfile. If there are any frameworks that are in both your local Frameworks folder AND the Pods folder, then they are redundant and you should delete the local copy.

Comment: after deleting the xxx.framework briefcase icon, my project no longer compiles. lexical or preprocessor error

Comment: I got it to compile and deleted the framework from the project folder (only exist in the pod folder now) however build succeeds but no emulator?